# Obtener ID de dispositvo con FireBase

Tags: c#, net, firebase-messaging, dotnetcore, .net-6.0

Anteriormente se usaba FirebaseInstanceId, pero ya está depreciado.

Mi entorno de trabajo es

- Net 6.0
- Net MAUI

Para poder enviarle un mensaje (push notification) con el servicio de Google Firebase debe obtener previamente el ID del Dispositivo (FCM)

Si veo la documentación oficial sería así:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Actualmente probé con este paquete:
https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet
Pero no existe dicho método, y da la sensación que se usa para tareas del lado del servidor y no del cliente

Con esa idea mire este paquete, pero no veo nada similar:
[Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1)

Con xamarin se usaba este:
[Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging)